# Find files with matching patterns in a directory c#?

Tags: c#, .net, regex, io

```
 string fileName = "";

            string sourcePath = @"C:\vish";
            string targetPath = @"C:\SR";

            string sourceFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(sourcePath, fileName);
            string destFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(targetPath, fileName);

            string pattern = @"23456780";
            var matches = Directory.GetFiles(@"c:\vish")
                .Where(path => Regex.Match(path, pattern).Success);

            foreach (string file in matches)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(file); 
                fileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(file);
                Console.WriteLine(fileName);
                destFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(targetPath, fileName);
                System.IO.File.Copy(file, destFile, true);

            }
```

My above program works well with a single pattern.

I'm using above program to find the files in a directory with a matching pattern but in my case I've multiple patterns so i need to pass multiple pattern in `string pattern` variable as an array but I don't have any idea how i can manipulate those pattern in Regex.Match.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can put an **OR** in the **regex** :

```
string pattern = @"(23456780|otherpatt)";
```

Answer (score 4):

change

```
 .Where(path => Regex.Match(path, pattern).Success);
```

to

```
 .Where(path => patterns.Any(pattern => Regex.Match(path, pattern).Success));
```

where patterns is an `IEnumerable<string>`, for example:

```
 string[] patterns = { "123", "456", "789" };
```

If you have more then 15 expressions in the array, you may want to increase the cache size:

```
 Regex.CacheSize = Math.Max(Regex.CacheSize, patterns.Length);
```

see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.cachesize.aspx for more information.

Comment: Should be `Regex.Match(System.IO.File.GetFileName(path), pattern)` since `GetFileNames` returns full paths.

Answer (score 2):

Aleroot's answer is the best, but if you wanted to do it in your code, you could also do it like this:

```
   string[] patterns = new string[] { "23456780", "anotherpattern"};
        var matches = patterns.SelectMany(pat => Directory.GetFiles(@"c:\vish")
            .Where(path => Regex.Match(path, pat).Success));
```

Comment: This is highly inefficient, as the Directory.GetFiles() call will be executed once per pattern. It would be better if you reverse the operations: Directory.GetFiles(...).SelectMany(file => patterns)...

But both of these will return the same file twice if it happens to match two of the expressions. See my answer for a solution that doesn't do that, and is even more efficient as a result (it will stop matching as soon as one pattern matches)

Comment: Indeed - and doing it with the regex is by far the best solution - as already mentioned :)

Answer (score 1):

In the simplest form you can do for example

```
string pattern = @"(23456780|abc|\.doc$)";
```

this will match files whith your choosen pattern OR the files with abc pattern or the files with extension .doc

A reference for the patterns available for the Regex class could be [found here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc.aspx)