# How rename the title of file from some folder if name contains some text

Tags: c#, file-io

I have in project one folder for uploaded files, I want to check if in this folder exist files contains some text in title.
I want to rename the file if it contains text "test"

For example, in folder "/uploadedFiles/" I have 4 files:
**test_01.jpg, 
02.jpg, 
03.png, 
test_04.txt**

I want to rename the files: "`test_01.jpg`" to "`01.jpg`" and "`test_04.txt`" to "`04.txt`"

I can edit the files like this:

```
System.IO.File.Move("test_01.jpg", "test_01.jpg".Replace("test_",""));
```

I need to get list of files that contains "test" in title from this folder

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3775828/get-files-from-directory-with-pattern, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10893311/find-files-with-matching-patterns-in-a-directory-c, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2700039/how-to-collect-all-files-in-a-folder-and-its-subfolders-that-match-a-string, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3218910/rename-a-file-in-c-sharp. Please try to use the search, show what you have tried and explain where specifically yhou need help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will get you a list of matching files, and then move each one:

```
foreach (var file in Directory.EnumerateFiles("somePath", "test_*"))
{
    var newFileName = Path.GetFileName(file).Remove(0, 5);  // removes "test_"

    File.Move(file, Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(file), newFileName));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get the list files that contain *test* in their name:

```
var files = Directory.EnumerateFiles(folderPath, "*test*.*");
```

Also you can use regex to do this:

```
Regex reg = new Regex(@".*test.*\..*",RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

var files = Directory.GetFiles(yourPath, "*.*")
                     .Where(path => reg.IsMatch(path))
                     .ToList();
```

Comment: files can be with different extensions

Answer (score 1):

```
System.IO.DirectoryInfo dir = new System.IO.DirectoryInfo(folderPathToUploadedFiles);

IEnumerable<System.IO.FileInfo> fileList = dir.GetFiles("*.*", System.IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories);

IEnumerable<System.IO.FileInfo> fullfileinfo =(from file in fileList  where file.Name.Contains("test") select file);
```

Answer (score 1):

this code renames all files with the keyword "test_". it is NOT case sensitive due to the "ToLower()" call

```
        const string testKeyword = "test_";
        var testFilePaths = Directory.GetFiles(@"c:\tmp").Where(f => f.ToLower().Contains(testKeyword.ToLower()));
        foreach (var testFilePath in testFilePaths)
        {
            File.Move(testFilePath, testFilePath.Replace(testKeyword, string.Empty));
        }
```